# python: pip install xmltodict fails

Tags: python, pip

I would like to use Ansible on my ubuntu machine. I tried to use the ping module and it complains that it does not find the `xmltodict` python library. I thus wanted to install the missing module using pip. When I try:

```
pip install xmltodict
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 215, in main
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 583, in setlocale
return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

I am running Ubuntu16.04 LTS. How can I fiy this? thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/36394101/486919.

Comment: @edwinksl That actually solved my problem! Shell I post the solution here?

Comment: Sure, remember to attribute the source appropriately though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394101/pip-install-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting

Since I am running python2.7:

```
$uname -a
Linux tools1-itigo-tech 4.4.0-24-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 8 19:27:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$python --version
Python 2.7.11+
$unset LC_ALL
$pip install xmltodict
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 215, in main
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 583, in setlocale
return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
$export LC_ALL=C
$pip install xmltodict
Collecting xmltodict
Downloading xmltodict-0.10.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: xmltodict
Running setup.py bdist_wheel for xmltodict ... done
Stored in directory: /home/usr/.cache/pip/wheels/2a/dc/70/da8958d7089d994c8614bc38210f64855f09615e85707bf615
Successfully built xmltodict
Installing collected packages: xmltodict
Successfully installed xmltodict
```

Answer (score 1):

> export LC_ALL=C

this will do the trick